Why edgeFunctionEntry is null in my Next App?
edgeFunctionEntry.env in the following code is null causing the app to crash in production. What could be the reason?
/**
 * Create a module cache specific for the provided parameters. It includes
 * a runtime context, require cache and paths cache.
 */ async function createModuleContext(options) {
    const warnedEvals = new Set();
    const warnedWasmCodegens = new Set();
    const { edgeFunctionEntry } = options;
    const wasm = await loadWasm(edgeFunctionEntry.wasm ?? []);
    const runtime = new _edgeruntime.EdgeRuntime({
        codeGeneration: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? {
            strings: true,
            wasm: true
        } : undefined,
        extend: (context)=>{
            context.process = createProcessPolyfill(edgeFunctionEntry.env);

The crash is happening at this function. /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/sandbox/context.js:101:30
function buildEnvironmentVariablesFrom(injectedEnvironments) {
  const pairs = Object.keys(process.env).map((key) => [key, process.env[key]]);
  const env = Object.fromEntries(pairs);
  for (const key of Object.keys(injectedEnvironments)) {
    env[key] = injectedEnvironments[key];
  }
  env.NEXT_RUNTIME = "edge";
  return env;
}


Same problem here, we were somehow mixing old and new next versions during the build pipepline, due to a (turbo) caching error... After we cleared the cache it worked.
Hint is looking at the middleware-manifest.json, you will see the env prop is empty...

I ran into this exact error this past week and the cause was that I was building with Next.js 14.2.5 installed in my local application directory, but the global next installation that pm2 uses was 14.2.13.
The fix on my end was ensuring that the globally installed and project specific next module versions match, which I'm sure is best practice and I should have been doing anyway.
